# AS3 1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value. Error

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a beginner at scripting but have this error in my first script:

"1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value."

I'll give the reference of the error.

```
var vLeft:Boolean = false
var vRight:Boolean = false

if (vLeft=false && vRight=false) //Location of the error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing an = in your if condition:

```
var vLeft:Boolean = false
var vRight:Boolean = false

if (vLeft==false && vRight==false)
```